# Blazor WASM TargetFrameworks netstandard 2.1 and net5.0

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-5, .net-standard-2.1

I have a dotnet 3.1 blazor wasm hosted app using the oracle ef core provider.

I would like to upgrade the blazor wasm app to net5.0 but can't do it, because I can not upgrade my asp.net core project until oracle releases a ef core provider that's supports net5.0.

I have been trying to multitarget the blazor project but can't make it work. my asp.net project can't see that it's also a netstandard2.1 project.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have multi target Blazor WASM app, as the code for .NET 5 is different as well. `netstandard2.1` project is using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web SDK but `net5.0` project is `using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly` SDK. Also `netstandard2.1` project is using some packages such as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build` which is not used on .NET 5 version and so on...